# Url Rewrite Help required

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm still so new to url rewrite. Need some help here.

I'm trying to set a different subdomain name to each of the countries on my site.

Did some research, here's what i got

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$
    RewriteRule ^=(.*)$           http://mydomain.com/o9_advertiser/ad_list/ad_list.php?country=$1 [L,R]
```

Would appreciate it if anyone can provide some help here. Thanks.

Comment: What input URL are you attempting to match with `^=(.*)$`?

Comment: The subdomain capture you did in the `RewriteCond` will be available as `%1` in the `RewriteRule`, not `$1`, if that is your aim.

Comment: I'm trying to get the country after the equal sign. so it becomes country.mydomain.com. I changed it to %1 but it still doesn't work.

Comment: First: use `@user`  to notify user about your comment or post! Second: Do you want to have `usa.mydomain.com`  or `iran.mydomain.com` ?

Comment: @Death Hi. Yes. That's what i would like to have. But it seems like its rather hard. Can't seem to read my rewrite cond. The url still shows without rewriting itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.o9village\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) o9_advertiser/ad_list/ad_list.php?country=%1 [L]
```

In first line, it checks whether it's something like `iran.mydomain.com` or not? if yes, it goes to rewrite rule which redirect user  to `http://mydomain.com/o9_advertiser/ad_list/ad_list.php`  **internally** (User can not see the redirection in his/her browser).
if you use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) function in `ad_list.php`  to see `$_GET` array, you will see something like:

```
array(2) {
  ["country"]=>
  string(4) "iran"
  ["path"]=>
  string(9) "index.php"
}
```

**Edit:**
OK, Log into your CPanel account, create a sub-domain   `*.o9village.com`.  set Document Root to point at Document Root of your main domain `o9village.com`. Now, if you browse `iran.o9village.com`, you will see same page as `http://o9village.com/o9_advertiser/ad_list/ad_list.php?country=iran`

Comment: Hi. thanks for the explanation. Helps a little understanding this so new topic but it still can't work. It redirects to a not found page with this long url->http://search.maxonline.com.sg/main?InterceptSource=0&ClientLocation=sg&ParticipantID=zflj3p94j2yfy45e433eet7iejjmxgif&FailureMode=1&SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fsingapore.o9village.com%2F&AddInType=4&Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0. I guess its a not found page. But when i go to-> http://mydomain.com/o9_advertiser/ad_list/ad_list.php?country=%1. The page is able to load fine without any problems.

Comment: I'm sorry with my above comment. Should be **when i go to http://mydomain.com/o9_advertiser/ad_list/ad_list.php?country=iran. It shows the page properly

Comment: did you set proper DNS settings in your server?

Comment: DNS settings? It should be working since the rest of my site is functioning or is there something that i'm missing out?

Comment: When a user want to browse `iran.mydomain.com`, first his browser finds domain's IP address which if you haven't set, doesn't exits! you can ping your domain to check its IP. [Ping](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ping.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: So do i have to set settings for each of the subDomain? Or is it just the settings for the main domain (ie:my site->o9village.com).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31323/discussion-between-lawrence-and-death)